# extracting names from a list of dataframes in R: existing solutions not working

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function

I have a list of dataframes. Using rmarkdown I am trying to print the name of each dataframe, determine if there are negative values, and if there are negatives, add the lowest value to the entire dataframe.

The solutions I have found for printing names all point towards `names(df)` or `deparse(substitute(df))`. Neither of these solutions work. I thought lapply preserved names.

Second problem: Why is it printing NULL at the end and how do I prevent this?

code example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(0,1,2), c(0,2,1))
df2 <- data.frame(c(-1,2,3), c(0,1,2), c(0,2,1))
df3 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(0,1,2), c(0,2,1))
matrices <- list(df1, df2, df3)

negatives <- function(x){
  numNeg <- sum(x<0)
  smallest <- min(x)
  cat("\n\nNumber of negative expression values: ", numNeg)
  cat("\n\nSmallest value: ", smallest)
  x <- x - smallest
  cat("\n\nAll expression values positive: ", all(x>=0))
}

correction <-function(m) {
  positives <- all(m>=0)
  cat("\n\n\n", deparse(substitute(m)))
  cat("\n\nAll expression values positive: ", positives)
  if(positives == FALSE) {
    negatives(m)
  }
  
}

lapply(matrices, correction)
```

output:

```
 X[[i]]

All expression values positive:  TRUE


 X[[i]]

All expression values positive:  FALSE

Number of negative expression values:  1

Smallest value:  -1

All expression values positive:  TRUE


 X[[i]]

All expression values positive:  TRUE[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the list of dataframes. A simple way to do that would be to use `tibble::lst`

```
matrices <- tibble::lst(df1, df2, df3)
```

Change the `correction` to accept two arguments. A dataframe and name of the list.

```
correction <-function(m, y) {
  positives <- all(m>=0)
  cat("\n\n\n", y)
  cat("\n\nAll expression values positive: ", positives)
  if(!positives) {
    negatives(m)
  } 
}
```

You are not returning anything from `lapply` but just printing it in which case `lapply` returns a `NULL` which is why they are printed at the end. To avoid this you can use `iwalk` from `purrr`.

```
purrr::iwalk(matrices, correction)

#df1

#All expression values positive:  TRUE


# df2

#All expression values positive:  FALSE

#Number of negative expression values:  1

#Smallest value:  -1

#All expression values positive:  TRUE


# df3

#All expression values positive:  TRUE
```

Comment: How do I use y? `y <- names(matrices)` then call with `iwalk(matrices, y, correction)`? Also when I use iwalk it does not look like it is doing anything. At least no output is printing

Comment: If you use `lst`you'll see the names are already assigned and `names(matrices)` returns `#[1] "df1" "df2" "df3"`. `iwalk` automatically passes first argument as dataframe and second one as name so you don't need `iwalk(matrices, y, correction)`. When I run this code in the R console it prints output for me as shown in the answer. Where are you trying to run this code?